I want to well size my MAUI Android app icon
I'am trying to size my App Icon on MAUI Android but the icon is not well sized,it is cropped and have big size :
Here my csrproj:
<ItemGroup>
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" BaseSize="48,48" Color="#ffffff" />
</ItemGroup>

Here is the manifest :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.XXXXX" android:versionName="110.0" android:versionCode="110">


    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="Leafwords" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round">

        <service android:name="communityToolkit.maui.media.services" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
</manifest>

The Icon is well presented on IOS but not Android:
Here is the image on Android :

Here is the image on IOS :


.NET MAUI supports creating an adaptive launcher icon on Android 8.0 and higher, from the app icon.
Adaptive launcher icons are composed icons, using a background layer and a foreground layer, and an optional scaling value. For more information, see the Composed icon section.
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" ForegroundScale="0.65" Color="#512BD4" />
</ItemGroup>

The ForegroundScale attribute can be optionally specified to rescale the foreground image so that it fits on the app icon. It's a percentage value so 0.65 will be translated as 65%.

Hello This is not working I still can see only a part of the icon

The background image (Include attribute) must be specified for the  item. The foreground image (ForegroundFile attribute) is optional.

How to specify  "background image" please do you have an example?
